# Manually position JComponent inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I want to programmatically move my JLabel to a specific location inside my JPanel. I have tried `setLocation(int x, int y)`, but it doesn't work.
I am trying to not use any layout manager.

Comment: Post that edit as an answer and I'll upvote it. Figuring out the answer on your own is a good thing and should be rewarded. :)

Comment: +1 For updating the question. @oletus: Consider adding an answer with a simple example. http://sscce.org/

Comment: -1 for updating the question instead of answering his own question.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a great tutorial on how to layout your components without using a layout manager.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

> Creating a container without a layout manager involves the following steps.
>
> 1. Set the container's layout manager to null by calling `setLayout(null)`.
> 2. Call the Component class's `setbounds` method for each of the container's children.
> 3. Call the Component class's `repaint` method.