# java swing multiple jpanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Basically all I want to do is draw two rows of buttons for a lights out game (homework), but I don't know how to make both panels show up. I've pretty much almost no graphics before, and I don't really understand anything I'm doing.
The panels them selves work, but it just shows whichever I add second (I assume it's overwriting the previous panel)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nButtonsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many buttons would you like?");
    int nButtons = Integer.parseInt(nButtonsString);
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();

    myFrame.setTitle("Linear Lights Out Game.");
    myFrame.setSize(FRAME_SIZE);    


    JPanel control_buttons = new Linear_Controls();
    myFrame.add(control_buttons);

    JPanel lights = new LinearLightsPanel(nButtons);
    myFrame.add(lights);

    myFrame.pack();
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186835/how-to-add-multiple-components-to-a-jframe

Comment: you can find code related to your request from here :http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/TabColorExample.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myFrame.add(control_buttons);
myFrame.add(lights);
```

By default a JFrame uses a BorderLayout. Also, by default components get added to the `CENTER` of the BorderLayout. However the CENTER can only contain a single component so only the last component added is displayed. Try:

```
myFrame.add(control_buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Now the two components should show up.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples. Also take a look at the `Trail/Table of Contents` link to see other useful topics for basic Swing usage.

Comment: How do I implement BoarderLayout in a custom class? DoI just store the Layout object I give it in a field and let java do the rest?

Comment: @icaughtfireonce, I have no idea what you are asking. Read the tutorial for working examples and more detail explanations.

Comment: Never mind, I played with it and I guess I don't have to include the boarder layout in my constructor. This works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the 2 panels A and B and add them to another panel C. Then you add C to your frame.

A bit better explained: This is what you have now:

```
JPanel lights = new LinearLightsPanel(nButtons);
myFrame.add(lights);
```

But you would like something like:

```
JPanel lightsA = new LinearLightsPanel(nButtonsA);
JPanel lightsB = new LinearLightsPanel(nButtonsB);

JPanel lightsC = new JPanel();
lightsC.add(lightsA);
lightsC.add(lightsB);

myFrame.add(lightsC);
```